# React native expo app not building with eas

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, apk, eas

I am trying to build expo app and it passess all test but when it hit run gradlew line 551 it failes

204 actionable tasks: 204 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

And then this

Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I've been using different types of build abb apk   production preview it dose not work i have run npx expo-doctor and there is no issues

> Task :expo-keep-awake:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders

> Task :expo-keep-awake:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-keep-awake:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-keep-awake:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars

> Task :expo-keep-awake:extractDeepLinksForAarRelease

> Task :expo-keep-awake:mergeReleaseShaders

> Task :expo-keep-awake:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-keep-awake:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

> Task :expo-keep-awake:packageReleaseAssets

> Task :expo-keep-awake:prepareLintJarForPublish

> Task :expo-keep-awake:prepareReleaseArtProfile

> Task :expo-keep-awake:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-keep-awake:writeReleaseAarMetadata

> Task :expo-splash-screen:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders

> Task :expo-splash-screen:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-splash-screen:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-splash-screen:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars

> Task :expo-splash-screen:extractDeepLinksForAarRelease

> Task :expo-splash-screen:mergeReleaseShaders

> Task :expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-splash-screen:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

> Task :expo-splash-screen:packageReleaseAssets

> Task :expo-splash-screen:prepareLintJarForPublish

> Task :expo-splash-screen:prepareReleaseArtProfile

> Task :expo-splash-screen:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-splash-screen:writeReleaseAarMetadata

> Task :app:buildCodegenCLI SKIPPED

> Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED

> Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED

> Task :app:generatePackageList

> Task :app:preBuild

> Task :app:preReleaseBuild

> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets

warning: Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)

> Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor:compileKotlin

> Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor:compileJava NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor:classes

> Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor:jar

> Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor:inspectClassesForKotlinIC

> Task :expo:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo-application:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo-constants:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo-file-system:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo-font:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo-keep-awake:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo-splash-screen:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :expo:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageReleaseAssets

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:prepareLintJarForPublish

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:prepareReleaseArtProfile

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE

> Task :expo-modules-core:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-constants:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-application:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-font:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-keep-awake:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-splash-screen:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-modules-core:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-file-system:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-application:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-constants:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-file-system:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-font:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-keep-awake:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo-application:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo-constants:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo-file-system:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo-font:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo-keep-awake:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo-splash-screen:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :expo:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-application:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-constants:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-file-system:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-font:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-keep-awake:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-splash-screen:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-modules-core:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:extractReleaseAnnotations

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles

[stderr]
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

[stderr]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

[stderr]
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

[stderr]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:mergeReleaseJavaResource

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:syncReleaseLibJars

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:writeReleaseAarMetadata

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:createFullJarRelease

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a]

> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets

info Writing bundle output to:, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle

info Writing sourcemap output to:, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map

info Done writing bundle output

info Done writing sourcemap output

info Copying 28 asset files

info Done copying assets

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:2728:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"

[stderr]
typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle

[stderr]
:11514:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"

[stderr]
setTimeout(function () {

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:9474:108: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in function "onChange"

[stderr]
...lInstanceHandle ? (from && nativeFabricUIManager.setIsJSResponder(from.sta...

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:10095:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 264#"

[stderr]
cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:13845:30: warning: the variable "**REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK**" was not declared in anonymous function " 264#"

[stderr]
if ("undefined" !== typeof **REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK**) {

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:15730:5: warning:

[stderr]
the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"

[stderr]
setImmediate(function () {

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19906:12: warning:

[stderr]
the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]
fetch: fetch,

[stderr]
^~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19907:14: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]
Headers: Headers,

[stderr]
^~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19908:14: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]
Request: Request,

[stderr]
^~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19909:15: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"

[stderr]
Response: Response

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20059:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"

[stderr]
var reader = new FileReader();

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20106:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"

[stderr]
} else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {

[stderr]
^~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20108:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"

[stderr]
} else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20110:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"

[stderr]
...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20348:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 519#"

[stderr]
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19918:76: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 502#"

[stderr]
...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self || typeof ...

[stderr]
^~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23838:27:

[stderr]
warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 668#"

[stderr]
if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23861:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 668#"

[stderr]
"undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23971:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 668#"

[stderr]
};else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23986:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 668#"

[stderr]
... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:36127:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"

[stderr]
...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:103501:16: warning: the variable "SharedArrayBuffer" was not declared in function "from"

[stderr]
if (typeof SharedArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' && (isInstance(value, Shared...

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:108220:14: warning: the variable "atob" was not declared in function "decodeBase64URL"

[stderr]
return atob(value.replace(/[-]/g, '+').replace(/[_]/g, '/'));

[stderr]
^~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:

[stderr]
108225:16: warning: the variable "Buffer" was not declared in function "decodeBase64URL"

[stderr]
return Buffer.from(value, 'base64').toString('utf-8');

[stderr]
^~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:109170:7: warning: the variable "**magic**" was not declared in function "polyfillGlobalThis"

[stderr]
**magic**.globalThis = **magic**;

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:109412:23: warning: the variable "URL" was not declared in function "PostgrestQueryBuilder"

[stderr]
_this.url = new URL(url);

[stderr]
^~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:111021:40: warning: the variable "clearInterval" was not declared in anonymous function " 3330#"

[stderr]
_this3.heartbeatTimer && clearInterval(_this3.heartbeatTimer);

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:111258:31: warning: the variable "setInterval" was not declared in function "_onConnOpen"

[stderr]
this.heartbeatTimer = setInterval(function () {

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:111639:27: warning: the variable "TextDecoder" was not declared in function "_binaryDecode"

[stderr]
var decoder = new TextDecoder();

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:115692:7: warning: the property "justifyContent" was set multiple times in the object definition.

[stderr]
justifyContent: 'flex-start'

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:115683:7: note: The first definition was here.

[stderr]
justifyContent: 'center',

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:115701:7: warning: the property "justifyContent" was set multiple times in the object definition.

[stderr]
justifyContent: 'flex-start',

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:115697:7: note: The first definition was here.

[stderr]
justifyContent: 'space-between',

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:115947:7: warning: the property "justifyContent" was set multiple times in the object definition.

[stderr]
justifyContent: 'flex-start',

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr]
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:115943:7: note: The first definition was here.

[stderr]
justifyContent: 'space-between',

[stderr]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a]

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[x86]

> Task :app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths

> Task :app:generateReleaseResources

> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests

> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease

> Task :app:extractProguardFiles

> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin

w: Argument -Xopt-in is deprecated. Please use -opt-in instead

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/adapters/react/permissions/PermissionsService.kt:157:30 'getPackageInfo(String, Int): PackageInfo!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/core/utilities/EmulatorUtilities.kt:30:13 'SERIAL: String!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/Promise.kt:68:18 This declaration overrides deprecated member but not marked as deprecated itself. This deprecation won't be inherited in future releases. Please add @Deprecated annotation or suppress. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47902 for details

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/Utils.kt:8:3 Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/ActivityResultsManager.kt:52:24 Parameter 'activity' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/AppContextActivityResultRegistry.kt:119:51 'getParcelableExtra(String!): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/AppContextActivityResultRegistry.kt:180:26 'getParcelable(String?): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/AppContextActivityResultRegistry.kt:271:83 'getParcelable(String?): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/DataPersistor.kt:67:20 'getSerializable(String?): Serializable?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/DataPersistor.kt:85:26 'getSerializable(String?): Serializable?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/devtools/cdp/CdpNetworkTypes.kt:184:54 Parameter 'request' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/devtools/cdp/CdpNetworkTypes.kt:208:54 Parameter 'request' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/devtools/cdp/CdpNetworkTypes.kt:228:15 Parameter 'now' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/devtools/cdp/CdpNetworkTypes.kt:228:54 Parameter 'request' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/events/KModuleEventEmitterWrapper.kt:90:7 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt:88:33 Parameter 'null' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt:89:34 Parameter 'null' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt:130:5 Parameter 'null' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:24:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:27:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:44:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt:59:11 Parameter 'type' is never used

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/JSTypeConverterHelper.kt:44:17 'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[x86]

w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

[stderr]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

[stderr]

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable

[stderr]

> Android resource compilation failed

[stderr]
ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/assets_pp.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

[stderr]

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]
BUILD FAILED in 5m 10s

204 actionable tasks: 204 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Comment: stack here in the same issue, can't build my project, did you find a fix plz? I built my project in two OS Windows and Ubunto but still not working, my only doubt is about @expo/config-plugins and expo-splash-screen

Comment: @da45 , If I'm being honest I'm not sure what the issue was i had a few errors most of them i solved by switching from npm to yarn  and then also i had a asset named pp.png and that gave an error also so i changed it to dp and it was fine after that i could build

Comment: Same problem here. Do you got the solution? Could you share?